# Why does pushing and popping the same amount of times break my program?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, low-level

Im using x86-64 NASM on WSL Ubuntu.

I'm trying to use push/pop for function params, but for some reason it makes my program return " ".

```
section .text
        global _start
_start:
mov edx, len  
mov ecx, msg
push ecx
push edx
call println
mov eax, 1
int 0x80

println:
pop edx
pop ecx
mov ebx, 1     
mov eax, 4   
int 0x80        
ret

section .data

msg db "Hello world!",0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

this returns:

```
Command terminated by signal 11
```

Not too sure what's causing this. Does anyone know?
I would like to add that removing both the pushes and both the pops makes the program run perfectly fine again.

Comment: Your code is 32 bit code, yet you state you are programming for 64 bit mode.  Which one of the two is it now?

Comment: As for your error: recall that `call` pushes the return address on the stack.  So when you `pop edx` in `println`, you end up popping the return address, not the argument you pushed.  To fix this, either pass the arguments in registers or load them from the stack using something like `mov edx, [esp+4]`.

Comment: loading a 32-bit address like this `mov ecx, msg` is definitely wrong in 64-bit mode. And [`int 0x80` is also wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/995714). In WSL you can't even use it and in WSL2 you'll need to install the 32-bit subsystem

Comment: As @phuclv points out, you're loading the contents of the message (the first 4 bytes, or 8 bytes in 64-bit mode). You want the to load the address of `msg` instead.

Comment: @Jim, in  nasm, `mov ecx, msg` loads the address, not the contents. The problem is that in 64-bit mode, the address may not fit in 32 bits.

Comment: @prl oh, right. To load the contents it would be `mov ecx,[msg]`. My asm is beyond rusty.

Comment: @Jim, in some x86 assemblers, it does work the way you remembered.

Comment: @phuclv: Linux non-PIE executables have symbol addresses in the low 2GiB of virtual address space, so it's not wrong to put addresses into registers with `mov r32, imm32` in 64-bit code.  In fact that's optimal, and what compilers do if you use `-fno-pie`.  ([How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)).  That will also make `int 0x80` happen to work in a 64-bit executable.  Of course, 32-bit `push ecx` is not encodeable in 64-bit mode, so this could only have been assembled with `nasm -felf32`.